# LINQ dynamic query with Where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I need to achieve the following query with LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE name = 'FOO' AND ((month = 1 AND week = 1) OR (month = 1 AND week = 2) OR...);
```

The thing is the number of month-week pairs are dynamic.

The parameters from month and week are given in pairs. E.g.: 1-1, 1-2.
Then I tried splitting them with '-' but I just can't find a way to do the query. I have tried the following:

```
foreach (var p in periods)
     query = query.Where(x => x.Week == p.Week && x.Month == p.Month); // Won't work because the Where will be added as 'AND'
```

I know I could do something like if the parameters were static:

```
query.Where(x => (x.Week == 1 && x.Month == 2) || (x.Week == 1 && x.Month == 1));
```

But as they are dynamic I don't see a way of doing that.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What do you mean these pairs are dynamic? What's the problem with them?

Comment: For these kind of thing, you may take a look at predicateBuilder : http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @raderick I added some more info. Sorry, I thought it was simple enough. Raphael I will look

Comment: I disagree that the question has been asked before due to the fact that in this specific instance, PredicateBuilder is not the best solution to the problem given. Generating a SQL "IN" clause is a better solution and Giogos' answer reflects that. Is it just me or is there no way to contest when a question is flagged as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters for `week`, `month` are stored like this:

```
string[] parameters = new string[] {"1-1", "1-2"};
```

then you can use:

```
var result = products.Where(x => x.name == "FOO" && 
                            parameters.Contains(x.week.ToString() + 
                                                "-" + 
                                                x.month.ToString()));
```

The above linq query will return *any* row in `products` whose:

- `name = "FOO"` **and**
- `week - month` pair is contained in *any* of the `week - month` pairs of the `parameters` array.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to comment?

Comment: That actually isn't a bad idea. Thanks Giorgios, I will also have a look on PredicatesBuilder as well. :)

Comment: You could take it even one step further and stay in the integer realm like so:
            int[] parameters = periods.Select(p => (p.Month * 100) + p.Week).ToArray();
            products.Where(x => x.name == "FOO" &&
                            parameters.Contains((x.month * 100) + x.week));

...and yes, it worked for me!